# How to add parameter as seed_value to sequelize.rand() to get effect similar to ORDER BY RAND(seed_value)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to get something similar to

```
"SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND($seed) LIMIT $amount OFFSET $offset";
```

in sequelize.

I tried to give in the following format :

```
 order : [sequelize.random(seed_value)]
```

but it failed to randomise. Probably sequelize.random() doesn't accept paramters.

Comment: You can use `sequelize.fn`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65188025/1376618)