# How to pass a seed value to random order function in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

In SQL dialects you can sort by random and you can pass a seed to the random function in order to get a repeatable random order of rows.

In MySQL you'd do it like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY RAND("192.168.1.1")
```

I'm aware of how to use the `RAND` function when querying with Sequelize:

```js
users.findAll({
  order: [sequelize.random()],
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to pass a seed to the random function.

I've looked at the docs: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-random](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-random)

And it looks like the `sequelize.random()` function doesn't take any parameters.

Is this possible?

Comment: Worth noting that [another Stack Overflow user asked a similar question in October](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64315613/how-to-add-parameter-as-seed-value-to-sequelize-rand-to-get-effect-similar-to) and didn't receive any material answers/comments.

Comment: @esqew I didn't see that post when I was searching, but that's not good news. It might not be a supported feature yet. I just wanted to double check before I gave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish your query will work only in MySQL then just use `sequelize.fn`:

```
users.findAll({
  order: [sequelize.fn('RAND', '192.168.1.1')],
});
```

Comment: Just a correction, the actual function is `RAND` and not `RANDOM`. Could you edit your answer for anyone else who might stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 2):

Absent any official documentation mention of the issue, the [definition of the `sequelize.random()` method in `sequelize.js` (line 892)](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/src/sequelize.js#L892) shows that it doesn't accept any parameters currently, and simply functions as a method by which to properly build a query dependent on the specific RDBMS configured for use.

As such, it is safe to say that, as of this writing, this is currently **not supported** in `sequelize`'s `master` branch by default; @Anatoly's answer shows how you might be able to achieve this by leveraging `sequelize.fn` in your own project.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for looking into it! I might make a pull request to add it in but I marked @Anatoly's answer for the question since it's a workaround for right now.